# timing function call cost

Tags: c, linux, caching, timer, function-call

I'm trying to see how much time a function call takes using clock_gettime with CLOCK_MONOTONIC. I did this by subtracting the timer overhead from the time of the function call.

I think the time should be consistent but when I loop it, the first time is alway 3x larger than the rest. Also, the time I get outside the loop is different too. Does anyone know what's going on?

(running C on ubuntu 14.04.1)

---

**Edit**

I was confused as to why the first time in the loop was much larger than the others. I now realize that this probably has something to do with caching.

I think that the first loop caches the timer and function? 
But when the loop is over, are they uncached? 
(After the loop, the function call time got bigger)

Output:

```
Within loop:
timer   w.func  difference
198     128     18446744073709551546
85      78      18446744073709551609
68      80      12
64      70      6
70      68      18446744073709551614
Outside loop:
101     115     14
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NANO 1E9
#define CLOCK CLOCK_MONOTONIC
signed long long timediff(struct timespec *tstart_p, struct timespec *tstop_p)
{
    return ((tstop_p->tv_sec - tstart_p->tv_sec)*NANO + tstop_p->tv_nsec - tstart_p->tv_nsec);
}

void function()
{
}

int main()
{
struct timespec start, stop;
signed long long timepassed, timeroverhead;

printf("Within loop:\n");
printf("timer\tfunction\tdifference\n");

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &start);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &stop);
    timeroverhead = timediff(&start, &stop);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &start);
    function();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK, &stop);
    timepassed = timediff(&start, &stop);
    printf("%llu\t%llu\t%llu\n", timeroverhead, timepassed, (timepassed-timeroverhead));
}

clock_gettime(CLOCK, &start);
clock_gettime(CLOCK, &stop);
timeroverhead = timediff(&start,&stop);

clock_gettime(CLOCK, &start);
function();
clock_gettime(CLOCK, &stop);
timepassed = timediff(&start, &stop);
printf("Outside loop:\n");
printf("%llu\t%llu\t%llu\n", timeroverhead, timepassed, (timepassed - timeroverhead));


printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) tools

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have absurdly large values is that the unsigned difference `(timepassed - timeroverhead)` underflows. Try using signed integers.

Edit: by the way, substracting the timer overhead will not work as you think. The time between two clock_gettime calls with CLOCK_MONOTONIC represent the time difference regardless of the process, not the cpu time. This means that your process can be stopped by the kernel scheduler between your "timer overhead" measurement, leading to larger overheads than the in-process time.

Tl;dr: don't try to measure the timer overhead.

Edit2: You should definitely stick with CLOCK_MONOTONIC. The problem does not lie here.

Again, don't try to measure the timer overhead. There is a reason nobody does that, and that's because it is not constant between calls.
If you don't want the timer overhead to be significant, call the function you want N times, measure the time passed on the loop, then divide it by N. Otherwise, you will have to live with the timer overhead.

The only way to have that much precision while having no overhead is to use specific cpu opcodes like `rdtsc`, but this is of course not portable.